# Issue with putting data to my database using axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I'm learing mern stack and im building simple app when i can singup,singin ,make notes and displaying them on front end. Everything works fine except one thing. When im trying to make new note request done by axios passing null instead of my note.

User.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {type:String,required:true },
    password: {type:String ,required:true},
    note: [{type:String}]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema)
```

Note endpoint

```
app.post('/note/:user',(req,res) => {
    userSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.user)
      .then(foundUser => {
        foundUser.note = [...foundUser.note,req.body.note]

        foundUser.save()
          .then(() => res.json("note added"))
      })
})
```

Notes.js

```
import Axios from 'axios'


function Notes(props){
    const [notes,setNotes] = useState()
    const [newNote,setNewNote] = useState('')
    useEffect(() => {
        setNotes(props.note)
       
      }, [props.note])
    useEffect(() => {
        
    }, [notes]);
    

    const handleChange = (e) =>{
        setNewNote(e.target.value)
    }
    const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(newNote)
        const newNotes = {
            note : newNote
        }
        console.log(newNotes)
        Axios({
            method: "POST",
            data: newNote,
            withCredentials: true,
            url: `http://localhost:4000/note/${props.userid}`,
          })
    }
    return(
        <div>
            {
                notes ? notes.map(e => {
                    return (
                    <div> {e} </div>

                    )
                }) : null
            }
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input
                type='text'
                value={newNote}
                onChange={handleChange}/>
                <button type="submit">Add</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Notes
```

When im passing some note and then i look on my db instead of see my new note i see 'null'. Thats strange beacouse when im doing exact same request on postman

ex. http://localhost:4000/note/603ca08df021760f000aa1bb-> "userid"

```
{
    "note":"hey"
}
```

It works just fine and i have note "hey" on my db. But when i try to do that request by axios i have note null. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Add a print in your function server side endpoint to print the value of `req.body` I think you will see that it's not formatted as you excepted.

Answer (score 2):

You have a type here:

```
  Axios({
    method: "POST",
    data: newNote, <-------- // should be newNotes, maybe?
    withCredentials: true,
    url: `http://localhost:4000/note/${props.userid}`,
  })
```

What type is the `newNote` variable? Just a string? Then I guess you want to use the `newNotes` variable (object) for the axios request. Because the request you execute locally using postman uses an object as well (note string wrapped in: `{ note: "content"}`).

Comment: Okay it seems im an idiot and i passed wrong variable.Thank you thats right solution

Comment: I'm glad I could help you :). Please accept it as solution :).